# How to decode base64 string before use in camel context?

Tags: apache-camel, base64, javabeans

I'm using a bean in my Camel Context with the class org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration to get as key-value the properties saved in my DB. So, the values coming in base64, and I need to decode the values to use them on my routes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Like Ocp and Kubernetes tools do it inside . It is transferred to the application by decoding the encoded text. You can still do this in camel. this example about encrypt and decrypt using jasypt lib  from camel book. you  must implement a basic PropertiesParser.class for base64 . PropertiesParser a basic a interface . full example https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter14/configuration/src/test/java/camelinaction/SecuringConfigTest.java

```
JasyptPropertiesParser jasypt = new JasyptPropertiesParser();
    // and set the master password
    jasypt.setPassword("supersecret");   
    
    // we can avoid keeping the master password in plaintext in the application
    // by referencing a environment variable
    // export CAMEL_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=supersecret
    // jasypt.setPassword("sysenv:CAMEL_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD");
    
    // setup the properties component to use the production file
    PropertiesComponent prop = context.getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
    prop.setLocation("classpath:rider-test.properties");

    // and use the jasypt properties parser so we can decrypt values
    prop.setPropertiesParser(jasypt);
    
    return context;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Base64 Decoder from `java.util` package and use it with bean, exchange function or processor. Use `Base64.getDecoder()` or `Base64.getUrlDecoder()` to obtain decoder then use the decoder to decode base64 string to byte array which you can then convert to String with camels `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` or just creating a new instance with `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

```java
package com.example;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Decoder;

import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Base64tests extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void Test() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultMockEndpoint.message(0).body().isEqualTo("Hello World");

        template.sendBody("direct:decodeBase64", "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=");

        resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        
        return new RouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                
                from("direct:decodeBase64")
                    .routeId("decodeBase64")
                    .bean(new Base64Decoder())
                    .log("${body}")
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                    .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }
}

class Base64Decoder{

    public byte[] decode(String encodedValue){

        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedValue);
    }
}
```

Using exchange function:

```java
.setBody().exchange( e -> { 
                            
    String encodedBody = e.getMessage()
        .getBody(String.class);
    
    return  Base64.getDecoder()
        .decode(encodedBody); 
})
```